# Designing Database For Books application

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

i am designing database for books application. I have main table **Books** and its child table is **Chapters**, chapters child table is **Sections**, So here is the problem, that some chapters has also divided into 3 steps **chapter Name -> Part 1 -> 
Divisions 1**  and each chapter consist on sections and sections also divided on to further 3 steps **Section -> sub Sections**.

Question: How can i manage chapter's parts and divisions because it is not compulsory that each chapter has its parts and and divisions and same question is for sections because some sections has sub sections or some sections are not.

Below i mention the structure of the book.

```
Book Name:
    Chapter 1
        section 1
        section 2
    Chapter 2
        Part 1
            Division 1
                Section 1
                section 2
                    sub section 2(1)
                    sub section 2(2)
            Division 2
                section 1
                section 2
            Division 3
                section 1
                section 2
        Part 2
            section 1
            section 2
    Chapter 3
        section 1
        section 2
```

So how can i do this in mysql ?

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no concrete structure, I would create tables for

Books (book details)

and

BookPart (part details
          , type - e.g section, division, chapter
          , parent book part)

Answer (score 0):

My suggested stucture -

```
Books 
Chapters -> contain section
section ->  Division,Part (Division,Part can be null)
sub section -> section
```

Or

```
Books 
Chapters -> contain section,Division,Part,subsectionID (Division,Part can be null)
sub section -> section
```

Sample Data

**Books**

> Book 1

**Chapters**

```
id  bookID   name        sectionid        
  1 |      | Chapter 1 |  1 
  2 |      | Chapter 1 |  2
  3 |      | Chapter 2 |  3
```

**section**

```
id | name      | Division   | part   |Sub id (zero or one )
1  | section 1 | null       | null   | 
3  | Section 1 | Division 1 | Part 1 |
```

**sub section**

```
 id | name  
    | sub section 2
```

You can follow this manner or

table structure 2 :

**Chapters**

```
id   bookID    name        section      part     division     sub cat Id 
  1 |  1     | Chapter 1 |  section 1 | null   | null       |  null
  2 |  1     | Chapter 1 |  section 2 | null   | null       |  null
  3 |  1     | Chapter 2 |  section 1 | Part 1 | Division 1 |  1
```

**sub section**
 id | name

```
  1  | sub section 2
```

Based on your available data you can decide which one is more suitable for you. better u draw er diagram and decide your table structure. because by that way you can easily normalize your tables according to your requirement

Comment: chapters also divided into parts and divisions